# CakePHP: include fieldname alias under related model

Tags: cakephp

I am willing to group MySQL results by a column, and also count the records which belong to the same category:

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('UserCheckin.id', 'UserCheckin.capital_id', 'COUNT(UserCheckin.id) as capital_checkins'), 
    'group' => 'UserCheckin.capital_id'
));
```

The problem is that `capital_checkins` is grouped as a separate key in the returned array, whilst I would like it to be under the `UserCheckin` model. Here's how the results are returned:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [UserCheckin] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [capital_id] => 10
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [capital_checkins] => 2
            )

        [Capital] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [name] => London
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
       ...
    )
```

)

Is there a way to include the alias under `UserCheckin` model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cakephp 1.3 you can use [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields):

in your `UserCheckin` model:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'capital_checkins' => 'COUNT(UserCheckin.id)'
);
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**: As @Rob Wilkerson correctly notices, adding a virtual field with aggregate function permanently to your model will [probably] mess up your `find` queries which do not have a `GROUP BY` (implicitly group all rows in MySQL or just fail with SQL error in SQL Server). Solution is to add a virtual field temporarily at a runtime before query that uses it:

```
$this->virtualFields['capital_checkins'] = 'COUNT(UserCheckin.id)';

$result = $this->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('UserCheckin.id', 'UserCheckin.capital_id', 'UserCheckin.capital_checkins'), 
    'group' => 'UserCheckin.capital_id'
));

//reset virtual field so it won't mess up subsequent finds
unset($this->virtualFields['capital_checkins']);

return $result;
```

Comment: the other solution would be to do that manually after the find query. but the virtual field way is cleaner and more beautiful :)

Comment: Can you use virtual fields for aggregate values? It doesn't sound right to me, but I haven't tried it. I wouldn't have thought so since it requires grouping.

Comment: @Rob Wilkerson Indeed, I was mistaken! including a virtual field automatically adds an implicit grouping by all rows! Thanks for noticing, I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what problems will the virtualFields raise if they are not added only at runtime?

Comment: If you add virtual field permanently in your model, it will apply to all queries. And in case if a) some query does not have a `GROUP BY` clause, AND b) the virtual field contains an aggregate function (`COUNT`, `SUM`, etc.) - this query will return only one row (because all rows will be automatically grouped by MySQL to calculate an aggregate). So if some of your `find()` queries on model with aggregate virtual field **do not** contain a grouping - you should use runtime virtual field.

Comment: Oh, OK, I got it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question though...why do I have to write `'COUNT(UserCheckin.id) as capital_checkins'` in the fieldlist if I declare the virtualField? It works fine if I specify `UserCheckin.capital_checkins`. Or am I missing something (again)?

Comment: It works probably because you've left `'COUNT(UserCheckin.id) as capital_checkins')` in your `fields` array passed to find? Well if it's so, in case of runtime virtual field it doesn't make much difference, however I'd still recommend to remove this from `fields` and set `virtualFields` normally (not just alias). Otherwise your code will be quite perplexing for someone looking at it later.

Comment: This is what I've done. I've asked only because in your code example you left the `count` part in the fields array. I have the `count` in my `virtualFields`, and the `UserCheckin.capital_checkins` in my `find` and everything seems to be OK. I've asked only to be sure I don't need the `count` in the `find` (as your example states).

Comment: Whoops, that's a mistake, i'll fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
'COUNT(UserCheckin.id) as UserCheckin__capital_checkins'
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-in-sql-queries

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.